# Верстка карточки пользователя

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем доброго вечере! Подскажите пожалуйста как сверстать этот элемент слайдера(фото прикрепила). Ситуация следующая, при наведение мишки на блок картинки, она должна стать темнее и в низу должны появится кнопки соц сетей.
Затемнить блок с картинкой при наведении я могу, а вот как сделать так, чтобы одновременно появились соц сети, этого я не умею) В CSS же нету никаких условий типа И, ИЛИ.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте код. Если кратко просто для блок с  иконками позицонируте абсолютно, добавляете `display: none` и по `hover` на карточку показываете

Comment: @E_K так а как так написать?) Я же не могу: if (.icon:hover){display} else {display:none} )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.c-card {
  width: 200px;
}
.c-card__img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.c-card__img-wrapper::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
}
.c-card__social {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.c-card:hover .c-card__img-wrapper::after {
  opacity: .7;
}
.c-card:hover .c-card__social {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-card">
  <div class="c-card__img-wrapper">
    <img class="c-card__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
    <div class="c-card__social">Social</div>
  </div>
  <p>Name Surname</p>
</div>
```